# Computing the integral $\int_{0}^{\theta}\frac{x^{a}}{(bx^{2}+c)^{5}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to compute the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\theta}\frac{x^{a}}{(bx^{2}+c)^{5}}dx,
\end{equation}
where $b,c,\theta>0$ and $a>2$?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: is a natural or real number? if natural, we have form of P(x)/Q(x) (polynomials) under integral

Comment: I guess partial fractions would work here, $x$ is real

Comment: my question about a, not x

Comment: $a$ is a natural number

Comment: I suppose that the antiderivative would be a gaussian hypergeometric function. Are you supposed to know about it ?

Comment: I don't know about this function, but how does one proceed?

Comment: To avoid the hypergeometric function try dividing the function into two sets, one with odd $a$ and the other with even $a$. With odd $a$ you can start by repeated integration by parts and finally integrating terms of the form $\int \frac{x}{\left(b x^2+c\right)^n} \, dx$. At odd $a\ge9$ a log term appears. Even $a$ is different with an ArcTan term appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^\theta\dfrac{x^a}{(bx^2+c)^5}~dx$

$=\int_0^{\theta^2}\dfrac{(\sqrt x)^a}{(bx+c)^5}~d(\sqrt x)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{\theta^2}\dfrac{x^\frac{a-1}{2}}{(bx+c)^5}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{b\theta^2}{c}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{cx}{b}\right)^\frac{a-1}{2}}{(cx+c)^5}~d\left(\dfrac{cx}{b}\right)$

$=\dfrac{c^\frac{a-9}{2}}{2b^\frac{a+1}{2}}\int_0^\frac{b\theta^2}{c}\dfrac{x^\frac{a-1}{2}}{(x+1)^5}~dx$

$=\dfrac{c^\frac{a-9}{2}}{2b^\frac{a+1}{2}}\int_0^\frac{\frac{b\theta^2}{c}}{\frac{b\theta^2}{c}+1}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)^\frac{a-1}{2}}{\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}+1\right)^5}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)$

$=\dfrac{c^\frac{a-9}{2}}{2b^\frac{a+1}{2}}\int_0^\frac{b\theta^2}{b\theta^2+c}x^\frac{a-1}{2}(1-x)^\frac{7-a}{2}~dx$

$=\dfrac{c^\frac{a-9}{2}}{2b^\frac{a+1}{2}}B\left(\dfrac{b\theta^2}{b\theta^2+c};\dfrac{a+1}{2},\dfrac{9-a}{2}\right)$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)

Comment: This answer or hint (depending on how the question is interpreted) transforms the problem from evaluating/computing the original integral to evaluating/computing the incomplete beta function, primarily as a function of $a$. I suppose it will be interesting to compare, for a given value of $a$, the computational efficiency of evaluating the answer in terms of elementary functions using the incomplete beta function as a starting point vs. say evaluating directly, using integration by parts or some other method.

Comment: @Harry Peter Thanks, I would like to simplify this further, but I couldn't find any bounds on $B(a,b,c)$. Are you aware of any upper bounds on $B(a,b,c)$?